# Is accessing the environment variables directly from AWS amplify considered a safe practice when I need my API keys for my React application?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I have several API keys that I do not want displayed in my source code when I deploy my application.

The [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) warns the following:

```
WARNING: Do not store any secrets (such as private API keys) in your React app!

Environment variables are embedded into the build, meaning anyone can view them by inspecting your app's files.
```

I accessed my variables by getting the keys from my local `.env` file. I assume the process is similar for AWS Amplify:

```
  accessKeyId: process.env.REACT_APP_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.REACT_APP_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

I often read about people able to find my keys if they "know where to look." Am I taking the proper measures to safeguard against this? I went through my files in the debugger in Firefox and couldn't find my `.env` file there.

The `.env` file was added to my `.gitignore` file so it does not exist in my remote repository.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common use case. Many customers use the [AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) to store and retrieve credentials at runtime. [Here's a blog post](https://medium.com/@mda590/simple-secrets-management-via-aws-ec2-parameter-store-737477e19450) that describes the process.

Comment: Hi Dennis, thank you for answering. This is definitely a useful resource. With regards to my question though, is there an issue with me just acquiring the keys from my environment variables directly?

Comment: It is considered good practice not to store any credentials locally on the machine. The usage of IAM Roles would be the most straight-forward option. If this isn’t possible, access credentials should be securely stored away, e.g. using AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store or AWS Secrets Manager. An additional benefit of this approach is that it not only strongly improves security, but it also allows to restrict and monitor access to those credentials, as the retrieval of the credentials can be protected through additional IAM permissions and is automatically logged in AWS CloudTrail.